# dlib python face encoding vs c++ face encoding

Tags: python, c++, dlib

I'm trying to produce the same face encoding in C++ that this python wrapper library gives:
https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/face_recognition/api.py

C++ code:

```
    frontal_face_detector detector;
    ...
        for (auto face : detector(img, numberOfTimesToUpsample))
        {
            auto shape = sp(img, face); //sp = shape_predictor 5 face landmarks same as python lib
            matrix<rgb_pixel> face_chip;
            extract_image_chip(img, get_face_chip_details(shape,150,0.25), face_chip); // Chip size and padding same as dlib python settings
            faces.push_back(move(face_chip));
            coords.push_back(face);
        }
    ...
        std::vector<dlib::matrix<float,0,1>> face_descriptors = net(faces, 16); // net is dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1 same as python lib
    ...
```

The python library upsamples once by default, and uses the small (5 point) shape predictor,

so I invoke the c++ code with `numberOfTimesToUpsample` as 1, and as my c++ code doesn't do the jittering, then I invoke the python code as:
`encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(image, num_jitters=0)[0]`

However, when I run an image with a face through both systems, the encodings come out quite different. For example, the c++ output of the first few dims:

```
-0.131519
0.0520326
0.0556113
-0.101895
-0.165266
```

And the python:

```
-0.14469159
0.04349349
0.03403644
-0.1062524
-0.18296713
```

I've examined the dlib C++-Python API for computing encodings here: https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/tools/python/src/face_recognition.cpp and cannot really see any major differences other than not casting everything to `double`.

**Edit**: I've tried converting to double as well. All the numbers are just the same.

I've tried building my project linked to the .so file that the python dlib library comes with. Still got the same numbers.

I checked that my method of reading in the image data produces the same RGB pixel values as the python PIL.Image reading-into-numpy-array does. Everything looks fine there.

I'd like to reliably be able to produce the same output.
What am I missing?

Comment: _other than not casting everything to `double`_ Even this may make a difference. I once had a hard time about failing tests where my `sin()` wrapper didn't compute the same like `std::sin()`. Finally, I found out that one of them did conversion to `double` and back to `float` where the other just computed in `float`. I was not aware that such peculiarity makes a difference. Should've read the [Floating Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) before... ;-)

Comment: @Scheff I converted to double just to check. All the numbers are still the same.

Comment: This is good (just to exclude this as possible reason). Is there any global configuration which could cause the difference. I assume that Python is just a wrapper around some DLL (written in C or C++). So, by-passing the Python API and accessing the wrapped functions directly shouldn't make a difference. This leaves the only reasonable assumption that something else is done in Python which you overlooked and didn't in C++...

Comment: Python extensions usually need some kind of initialization e.g. for wrapper objects. (We just digged in our own today.) Without knowing details, this is where I would search also.

Comment: Yep, so the dnn initializations are all the same. Both are using the same model dat files.

Comment: I even built my project linked to the .so file that the python dlib library comes with. Still got the same numbers.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this problem?

Comment: @jkt123 I think it's related to the colour model, but still need to test (https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/494#issuecomment-441162936) It's on my long, long TODO list!